# Is there any way to Copy and Paste from one file(from beginning to end) to another using SED and AWK?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Is there any way to Copy from one file(from beginning to end)  to another using SED and AWK?

I want to do 'cp file1 file2' using SED or AWK.

Comment: It is not! @don_crissti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the only way with sed, but this should do the trick:

```
sed -n 'p' file1 > file2
```

Please beware: awk and sed are line orientated so you could encounter problems with binary files, esp. file w/o end of line characters.

(I just noticed: I am using i/o redirection so my anwser might be considered as not quite correct on technical terms; though it does work ;-)

Comment: `sed` autoprints by default, just so you know...

Answer (score 2):

As far as awk goes, you can write to file. This behavior is specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) (see "Output Statements").

```
awk '{print > "my_output.txt"}' input.txt
```

With sed, one could use `w` flag, which apparently is also specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/sed.html):

```
sed 'w output.txt' input.txt
```

Comment: not `sed 'w file2' file1`?

Comment: @steeldriver   Didn't know about that one :) Will edit answer in a sec

Comment: So what is the difference between `sed 'w output.txt' input.txt   `and     `sed -n 'p' file1 > file2` ?

Comment: `sed 'w output.txt' input.txt` does not work.  `sed -n 'p' file1 > file2 ` work

Comment: @Christiano difference is that  `sed 'w output.txt' input.txt` uses `sed` flag to do the job. In second command ` > file2`   is redirection done by the shell and it has nothing to do with sed.